# How to check if a variable or object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always thought I could just check an undefined var by comparing it to undefined, but this is the error I get in the chrome console :

[image]

How how do i check for the object jQuery being undefined ?

EDIT :

[image]

if(jQuery) is giving me problems too

EDIT :

solution :

`if(window.jQuery)` works. 
`typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined'` works too.

Could anyone explain why ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531059/how-to-check-if-a-variable-or-object-is-undefined/8531076#8531076][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531059/how-to-check-if-a-variable-or-object-is-undefined/8531076#8531076

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531059/how-to-check-if-a-variable-or-object-is-undefined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several solutions:

1. Use `typeof`. It is a special operator and will never result in a `ReferenceError`. It evaluates to "undefined" for, well, the `undefined` value *or* for a variable which does not exist in context. I'm not a fan of it, but it seems very common.
2. Use `window.jQuery`. This forces a "property lookup": property lookups never fail, and return `undefined` if said property does not exist. I've seen it used in some frameworks. Has the downside of assuming a context (usually `window`).
3. Make sure the variable is "declared": `var jQuery; if (jQuery) { /* yay */ }`. Doesn't seem very common, but it is entirely valid. Note that `var` is just an annotation and is hoisted. In the global context this will create the "jQuery" property.
4. Catch the `ReferenceError`. Honestly, I have never seen this nor do I recommend it, but it would work.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

**Process 1:**

```
if (jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
}
```

**Process 2:**

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
}
```

Comment: No, this can throw a ReferenceError, as what is being shown in the post.

Comment: Process #2 is safe/correct here. Often times I see `===` used exclusively with `typeof`, but, looks valid.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.satyakomatineni.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=satya&reportId=2129)

```
if(typeof jQuery == "undefined") { 
  document.write("undefined"); 
}else{ 
   document.write("Exists"); 
}
```

Comment: Although this "cheats" with `var test=1` as then the context is not the same :) It would still be valid for this situation without it, though.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can do

```
if(typeof X == 'undefined')
```

But there are resources loader you might want to take a look at. And the answer given before me is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

The variable called "jQuery" in your code has never been declared, so it will throw an error like "xxx(variable name) is not defined".

You can use the `typeof` operator to check is a variable is undefined or not

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :
if( typeof jQuery !== 'undefined')

or

Do what is recommended by mozilla

if('jQuery' in window)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Answer (score -1):

`if(jQuery)` should be enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: No. It might throw a ReferenceError (what the above is in the post).