# How to distinguish between a variable that is not declared and a varrable that is declared but not be assigned any value?

Tags: javascript

Both scenario, the typeof the variable will be "undefined".
But undeclared variable will raise a exception.

Is there a easy way to handle this?

Comment: Can you specify some sort of code sample or a more in-depth description in your question?

Comment: You could use the `in` operator to check for variables defined (with the value `undefined`) in the global scope, or on objects. But it's not possible for local variables created inside a function as they're not accessible programmatically. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3390426/165737) from an older thread. For local variables created inside a function using a `try..catch` block looking for a `ReferenceError` seems to be the only solution as also suggested in @pst's linked answer.

Comment: Why are you trying to use variables that you haven't declared? If you get a `ReferenceError`, that means it's time to fix some code.

Comment: @pst: The first sentence indicates that he did, and why it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find the question (and my answer) in [How to check if a variable or object is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531059/how-to-check-if-a-variable-or-object-is-undefined/8531113) relevant. In general, I view *any* access to an "undeclared variable" a programming error.

However, this *particular case* can *only** be detected with the use of detecting for a `ReferenceError` exception. But, **yuck, yuck, yuck!** Remember variable declarations are a *static lexical construct*, ignoring the quirks with property-variables of the global object.

`ReferenceError`, and now "strict", exist for a reason and I suspect this is an X-Y problem. I do not even recommend the use of `typeof` for this purpose: fix the code :-)

Happy coding.

---

*It has been pointed out that `"variable" in window` will also [and only] work for global "variables" (they are really just properties that don't need be qualified in all contexts).

Comment: +1 for `ReferenceError` and "strict" exist for a reason, for the X-Y problem, and for the `typeof` non-recommendation. So overall a big +1!

Comment: Couldn't have gotten it better myself. +1.

Answer (score 1):

if property we want to check in object whether that it exists or not, even if its undefined.

we will use one of these:
**'prop' in obj**(to check for properties from prototype chain) or
**obj.hasOwnProperty('prop')**

we need to use methods above to check if property exists as accessing property that has not been declared in object will also return undefined.

```
var o={};
o.c=undefined;
o.c===undefined; //is true
o.a===undefined; //is true as well even though c exists while a doesn't
```

commonly not a problem as nobody really declare undefined properties much, but when do so do it like this.

```
o.c=''; //when it can be string or 
o.c=null; //to clearly indicate that its nothing.
then
o.c === undefined will return false!
note!!!
null ==  undefined //true while
null === undefined //false that's why use three equals to test
```

For variables not declared and are not inside object. When accessed The compiler will return (reference)error.
If it doesn't it means its being treated as a global property, **window object** property, and was not declared, at least in all parent scope, so it will be undefined just as `o.a` was at top. it will become `window.prop`.

```
so x; //error
but x=3; //no error assumed to be global object.
just like o.abcd = 3; would...
make(declare) a property abcd in object o valued(assigned) 3 all at once.
```

To avoid properties to become a global variable we use **var keyword inside function**, like this `var k;`

One thing you can do about this catch the reference error when throw for a variable that doesn't exist and are thought to be a variable itself.

```
try {
x
} catch(e){//code to run when x is not declared let alone defined.}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `try`:

```
var a;
try {
    a;
    alert('a');
} catch(e) { /* a not defined */ }
try {
    b;
    alert('b');
} catch(e) { /* b not defined */ }
alert('done');
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eqSKY/)

Answer (score 0):

You should never be attempting to access undeclared vars if you're writing clean JS. To avoid such pitfalls (among many others) start LINTing your JS with http://www.jslint.com/ or http://jshint.com/ .

A good read to help you understand the LINT tools and reasoning behind their findings is Crockford's Book, JavaScript: The Good Parts ( [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0596517742](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) ).