# Check whether JavaScript variable has once been declared?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to distinguish between a variable that is not declared and a varrable that is declared but not be assigned any value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675839/how-to-distinguish-between-a-variable-that-is-not-declared-and-a-varrable-that-i)

I want to see in my code whether someone in the past has already declared the `a` variable.

I thought about this:

```
alert(typeof(a)=="undefined") //true
```

but then I tested:

```
var a;
alert(typeof(a)=="undefined") //also true !
```

so how can I check whether there was `var a` somewhere in the past?

Comment: [In javascript, how to distinguish between a variable that is not declared and a varrable that is declared but not be assigned any value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675839/in-javascript-how-to-distinguish-between-a-variable-that-is-not-declared-and-a)

Comment: There is [not much difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675839/in-javascript-how-to-distinguish-between-a-variable-that-is-not-declared-and-a) between `var a; // no value` and not creating `a` at all. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to check whether a variable is (locally) declared is to test the value, and see if any [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) is thrown.

```
try {
    a === 1; // Some statement to trigger a look-up for the a variable
    alert("a is declared!");
} catch (e) {
    alert("a is not declared!");
}
```

Comment: hi rob its RoyiNamir , I run out of available question for today... I guess the try catch statment are the only option here.... yhanks.

Comment: @doomday1, there are probably other options. You just need to tell us what are you trying to do as you forgot to state this in your original question. The real question is why do you need to test against something like this?

Comment: @Royi Hello ;) In the future, you might want to use the search feature to check whether the question has already been asked. That saves you some time, and you won't run out of questions.

Comment: `a;` would be enough to trigger a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @Rob did you see the title of the duplicated question ? how can you compare my search string : `check if javascript variable as already been declare` to this long  and unfindable result : `How to distinguish between a variable that is not declared and a varrable that is declared but not be assigned any value?`

Comment: @doomday1 Dont type whole sentences. Type the keywords and tags. For example, the following will show both questions (yours + duplicate):`[javascript] variable declared`

Comment: and if i want to look up whether property in object has been declared but is not defined so it'd be undefined. How would i check. Because `var o={}; o.c=undefined. or Object.defineProperty(o,'c',{...}); o.c == undefined //true and o.whoAmI == undefined //true..` When clearly one has been declared and on has not been.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). In your example: `'c' in o // true` and `'whoAmI' in o // false`. This includes any property inherited from the prototype chain. If you want to exclude the inherited values, use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675839/how-to-distinguish-between-a-variable-that-is-not-declared-and-a-varrable-that-i/18161908#18161908 i wrote answer there just for me to reference back.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't do this with local variables. Global variables, you can test with `'a' in window`.

```
console.log('a' in window);
   // false

a = undefined;

console.log('a' in window);
   // true
```

However, *why would you do this*? It looks like an extremely fragile way to build your program.

**EDIT**: I lied. This might work:

```
try {
  a
  console.log("a is declared");
} catch (x) {
  if (x instanceof ReferenceError) {
    console.log("a isn't declared");
  } else {
    // i have no idea why else this could throw an exception...
  }
}
```

Oh, one more thing: that better not be a `console.log` in a real application, or make sure you shim it in, because some browsers do not have `console` defined (such as Firefox without Firebug). That too would be a `ReferenceError`, btw...

Answer (score 0):

Initiate it with null, like:

```
var a = null;
```

And check for that.

Comment: I dont have control of the `var a` code

Comment: Than you can do something with try-catch as noted in the answer of Rob W