# How to check an undefined argument of the function? (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, arguments

There is some examples:

```
a = ''; //string
b = 0; //number 0
b1 = 0xf; //number 15
c = (function(){}) //function function (){}
d = []; //object
e = {}; //object [object Object]
f = void(0); //undefined undefined
```

but when I try pass undefined variable trougth function like that:

```
typeof qwerty; //undefined
function at(a){return (typeof a)+' '+a;}
at(qwerty); // ????
```

..i`v got an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: qwerty is not defined".
How can I (Is the shortest way exist to) create function isDefined(a,b) or another trick to reduce that expression?:

```
c=(typeof a!='undefined'&&a||b)
```

Clarification: If a is defined - c equals a, overwise - b, like "c=@a?:b" in php

**Edit:**

```
function ud(_a){return typeof window[_a]==='undefined'}

a=undefined; b=3;
alert((ud('a')?4:a)+(ud('b')?5:b));​
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and search google.com for 'undefined value in javascript' - with a bit of reading and trying (Tryit Editor!) you will find the correct answer yourself

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

```
function isDefined(variable, dflt) {
    return typeof variable === "undefined" ? dflt : variable;
}

var c = isDefined(a, b);
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined (Google Chrome 16...)

Comment: Thats a problem with how your calling the function, you'll need to provide some sample code + all these examples assume that the test variable has been declared,  is that not the case?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/grK5X
seems to be argument have to declare before pass trougth the function, but it can be undefined.

Comment: It fails because in that case `a` is undefined & *undeclared* - the act of passing it to a function fails as js cant resolve the symbol `a` to anything. Move the check to inline rather than a function; http://jsfiddle.net/grK5X/3/ also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531059/how-to-check-if-a-variable-or-object-is-undefined/8531113

Answer (score 1):

```
function def( a, b ) {
    var undef;

    return a === undef ? b : a;
}
```

And then:

```
var c = def( a, b );
// if a is defined - c equals a, otherwise b
```